# How do higher-order functions, like .map(), work internally in JavaScript?

Tags: javascript, node.js, dictionary, higher-order-functions

Everyone nowadays tries to use these kind of [higher-order functions](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Higher-order_function) to get promising result with writing less code. But I wonder how these functions works internally.

Suppose if I write something like

```js
var numbers = [16, 25, 36];
var results = numbers.map(Math.sqrt);
console.log(results); // [4, 5, 6]
```

I know that each element of 'number' array is iterating one by one, but *how*?

I tried to search for it, but I didn't get any satisfactory answer yet.

Comment: Have a look on polyfil of [Array.map](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/map)

Comment: It's a function called `map` which was added to the type Array. This function takes a function as a parameter which is then called while looping through the array. The return values of the function calls are then returned in an array.

Comment: map basically work like foreach for iterating the array means it will get all elements of array one by one and then apply the given command/operation on each element and then push it in to new array.

Answer (score 24, accepted):

`.map` is just a method that accepts a callback, invokes the callback for every item of the array, and assigns the value to a new array. There's nothing very special about it. You can even implement it yourself quite easily:

```js
Array.prototype.myMap = function(callback) {
  const newArr = [];
  for (let i = 0; i < this.length; i++) {
    newArr.push(callback(this[i], i, this));
  }
  return newArr;
}

var numbers = [16, 25, 36];
var results = numbers.myMap(Math.sqrt);
console.log(results); // [4, 5, 6]
```

To be fully spec-compliant, you'd [also need](https://tc39.es/ecma262/#sec-array.prototype.map) to check, among other things, that the `this` is an object, that the `callback` is callable, and to `.call` the callback with the second parameter passed to `myMap` if there is one, but those are details not important to a beginning understanding of higher-order functions.

Comment: This reminds me of [some other answers](https://stackoverflow.com/search?q=Array.prototype.myMap)…

Answer (score 6):

I guess every vendor is supposed to implement it as per the [spec](https://www.ecma-international.org/ecma-262/6.0/#sec-array.prototype.map)

The actual implementation, for example V8 can be a bit complex, refer [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/56586401/427146) for a start. You can also refer v8 source in github but it may not be easy to understand only one part in isolation.

Quoted from above answer:

> V8 developer here. We have several different implementation techniques
>   for "builtins": some are written in C++, some in Torque, some in what
>   we call CodeStubAssembler, and a few directly in assembly. In earlier
>   versions of V8, some were implemented in JavaScript. Each of these
>   strategies has its own strengths (trading off code complexity,
>   debuggability, performance in various situations, binary size, and
>   memory consumption); plus there is always the historical reason that
>   code has evolved over time.

ES2015 spec:

1. Let *O* be ToObject(**this** value).
2. ReturnIfAbrupt(*O*).
3. Let *len* be ToLength(Get(*O*, `"length"`)).
4. ReturnIfAbrupt(*len*).
5. If IsCallable(*callbackfn*) is **false**, throw a **TypeError** exception.
6. If *thisArg* was supplied, let *T* be *thisArg*; else let *T* be **undefined**.
7. Let *A* be ArraySpeciesCreate(*O*, *len*).
8. ReturnIfAbrupt(*A*).
9. Let *k* be 0.
10. Repeat, while *k* < *len*

    1. Let *Pk* be ToString(*k*).
    2. Let *kPresent* be HasProperty(*O*, *Pk*).
    3. ReturnIfAbrupt(*kPresent*).
    4. If *kPresent* is **true**, then

       1. Let *kValue* be Get(*O*, *Pk*).
       2. ReturnIfAbrupt(*kValue*).
       3. Let *mappedValue* be Call(*callbackfn*, *T*, «*kValue*, *k*, *O*»).
       4. ReturnIfAbrupt(*mappedValue*).
       5. Let *status* be CreateDataPropertyOrThrow (*A*, *Pk*, *mappedValue*).
       6. ReturnIfAbrupt(*status*).
    5. Increase *k* by 1.
11. Return *A*.

Comment: I'm curious, the spec's `<li>` `list-style-type`s aren't copyable in Chrome nor FF. Did you write the numbers in manually, or is there a better method I'm missing?

Comment: @CertainPerformance lol. Copy HTML from source, HTML to markdown online tool.